# Cannot access file in linux using java

Tags: java, linux, spring, spring-boot, unix

I want to get the file and folder size. so I'm using `File()` class in java to get the file properties.
It works fine for me in windows. Using the same `File()` I'm not able to access the file in Linux.

```
Path root = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir")).getFileSystem()
                                    .getRootDirectories().iterator().next();
logger.debug("root path: {}", root);
File filePath = new File(root + path)
```

`root` + `path` = `"/" + logs`

Where logs is a folder present in Linux root

Note :
 Here I want to add details that, running my code as spring application deployed using docker container in Linux instance

Comment: Check that user running `java` have [UNIX permissions](https://www.guru99.com/file-permissions.html) to access this logs file/folder.

Comment: Why do you use `File` when you're already using `Path`?

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you should be using just `Paths.get("/logs")` instead.

Or maybe I don't understand your problem - if this is going to always be run on a Linux box, why do you need that first line? Do you plan to run this app on multiple File Systems?

Comment: Thank you, Fionn for your reply.   Don't get confused with the first line, Path root variable will return the root as String E.g for windows: it will return C:/ and for Linux, it just returns "/"   & already tried your way "/logs"